# Troubles with deploying Pivotal Cloud Foundry on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, cloud-foundry

I have been trying to install Pivotal Cloud Foundry on AWS and I have troubles with it.

In the section [upload-cert](https://docs.pivotal.io/pivotalcf/1-10/customizing/cloudform-template.html#upload-cert) mentioned that I need to create SSL Certificates for:

- *.system.example.com
- *.login.system.example.com
- *.uaa.system.example.com
- *.apps.example.com

So, I've created domain xxxxx.com on AWS Route53 and created a certificate on AWS ACM for domain and subdomains.

So, my questions are:

- do I need to create subdomains (system, login, uaa, apps) in AWS Route53
- do I need to bound my domain and subdomain somehow to PCF? Or the installation process had to do it for me?
- for now, if I open http://login.xxxxx.com/ it responses with 503. what can be the reason?
- what is the correct url to open the PCF UI?
- I have such error in Ops Manager. What can be the reason of such error?[image]
- The same about logs. When I tried to download logs for failed services it failed too. What can be the reason? [image]

Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason of the red instances on the Status page was that my AWS account had limit on number of instances and it failed to create VMs for this nodes. 
To find more information open Changelog (https://ops_manager_host/change_log) and the open log of the FAILED setup.

Answer (score 3):

> do I need to create subdomains (system, login, uaa, apps) in AWS Route53
>   do I need to bound my domain and subdomain somehow to PCF? Or the installation process had to do it for me?

You can create a wildcard subdomain (*.xxxxx.com) and alias using the instructions here: https://docs.pivotal.io/pivotalcf/1-10/customizing/cloudform-er-config.html#cname

> what is the correct url to open the PCF UI?

If you mean Ops Manager, it is whatever DNS entry you created and pointed to the Ops Manager public IP address in this step: https://docs.pivotal.io/pivotalcf/1-10/customizing/cloudform-om-deploy.html#create-dns

For the ERT UI, there is the Pivotal Apps Manager https://docs.pivotal.io/pivotalcf/1-10/console/index.html

which is usually apps.system.xxxx.com

You can see what system apps are deployed by connecting to Cloud Foundry using the CLI and seeing which apps are in the system org, and what their routes are.

> for now, if I open http://login.xxxxx.com/ it responses with 503. what can be the reason?

If the DNS has not been set up, I'm surprised you're getting any response whatsoever. Usually you get 503s when the routers connected to the load balancers are failing for some reason (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/classic/ts-elb-error-message.html#ts-elb-errorcodes-http503)

> I have such error in Ops Manager. What can be the reason of such error?

This would explain the 503s if the router is unhealthy. I would SSH into those machines and see what the logs say (in /var/vcap/sys/logs), which should tell you what is going wrong.